# 'No signature of method' error in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have bellow error.

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_dzdsudclts8lt5t6sfihabql2.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_dzdsudclts8lt5t6sfihabql2$_run_closure2) values: [build_dzdsudclts8lt5t6sfihabql2$_run_closure2@6a406f49]

**My app/build.gradle:**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (System.getenv()["CI"]) { // CI=true is exported by Codemagic
                storeFile file(System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PATH"])
                storePassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
                keyAlias System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_ALIAS"]
                keyPassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_PASSWORD"]
            } else {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wearemeridian.easyenglish"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "default"
        }
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            dimension "default"
        }
        tst {
            applicationIdSuffix ".tst"
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```